# Creating radio buttons that change color background and text using cookie values

Tags: php, html, cookies, request, radio-button

I have 3 files
login html
options php
homepage php

The idea is I pass the cookies username and pw from my login html file into my options php. In the options php, I have radio buttons to set colors for background in homepage php.

Where I am stuck is how do I request the color submissions to color the background in homepage php and display the color selected? Posted code below.

I am able to pass the cookie along without submitting any colors, but I don't know what to do to pass the color to change the colors of the next page.

login html
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<form action="http://localhost/options.php" method="post">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" minlength="6" maxlength="12"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{6-12}" required><br><br>
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" minlength="6" maxlength="12"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

`options php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    $password = htmlentities($_POST['password']);
setcookie('username', $username, time() + (1), "/");
setcookie('password', $password, time() + (1), "/"); 

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "http://localhost/homepage.php" method="POST">

<input type="radio" name="bgcRbtns" class="radioColor" value="red"> Red
         <input type="radio" name="bgcRbtns" class="radioColor" value="green"> Green
         <input type="radio" name="bgcRbtns" class="radioColor" value="blue"> Blue
         <input type="radio" name="bgcRbtns" class="radioColor" value="#AC4FC6"> Purple
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit2">
         <script>
   let radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('radioColor')
   console.log(radioButtons)
   window.onload = function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
         if (radioButtons[0].checked == true) {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
         }
         if (radioButtons[1].checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"
         }
         if (radioButtons[2].checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
         }
        }
         if (radioButtons[2].checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AC4FC6"
         }
      }
   
   for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
      radioButtons[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
         console.log(e)
         if (e.target.value == "red") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
         }
         if (e.target.value == "green") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"
         }
         if (e.target.value == "blue") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
         }
         if (e.target.value == "#AC4FC6") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AC4FC6"
         }
      })
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`homepagephp`

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to your custom page</h1>

<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    echo 'user is '  . $_COOKIE['username'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Password is '  . $_COOKIE['password'] . '<br>';


} else
    echo 'user not set';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try this on homepage.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_COOKIE['color']))
 {
   $color = $_COOKIE['color'];
  }
else
{
 $color  = "";
 }
?>
<body style="background-color:<?php echo $color ; ?>">
```

Basically you are storing cookie color into a variable and pass it on body style.
If cookie is set color will be cookie color else color will be blank

Comment: <?php
 if(isset($_COOKIE['submit2']))
 {

   $color = $_COOKIE['radioColor'];
   setcookie('radiocolor', $color, time() + (10000), "/");
  } but I still can't call it. Submit2 is my submit button from options.php.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).